# Nested classes and recursion

Tags: c#, reflection, class, recursion, nested

Say i have these two classes

```
public class Container
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}

public class Inner
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Inner2 Innert2 { get; set; }
}

public class Inner2 {}
```

How would i go, given an instance of the `Container` class find all nested class instances. Only really concerned about the classes not the strings etc.

Needs to be generic so that if Inner had a class it would still work. Also if there is a `List<>` or `IEnumerable` of a class it needs to find them too.

Cheers.

Comment: that is not a nested class, but I know what you mean. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120(VS.80).aspx

Comment: There is no recursive relationship between the classes in your code. Container contains a single instance of Inner, which only contains a text property. Please review your sample.

Comment: I dont see nested classes there. You meant properties of custom types right?

Answer (score 2):

Using Reflection would be the way to go. Here's a simple snippet of code that would allow you do get the properties of a class and, if the property is not of a value type, recursively call itself. Obviously if you want specific behavior with Enums or IEnumerable members, you'll need to add that.

```
public void FindClasses(object o)
{
    if (o != null)
    {
        Type t = o.GetType();
        foreach(PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
        {
            if(!pi.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                // property is of a type that is not a value type (like int, double, etc).
                FindClasses(pi.GetValue(o, null));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question would work if the code in your example was as such:

```
public class Container
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}

public class Inner
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Inner> MoreInners { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, you could either use an external iterator class to do the work, or build the recursion directly into the Container class. I will do the latter:

```
public class Container
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }

    public List<Inner> SelectAllInner()
    {
        List<Inner> list = new List<Inner>();
        SelectAllInner(Inner, list);
        return list;
    }

    private void SelectAllInner(Inner inner, List<Inner> list)
    {
        list.Add(inner);
        foreach(Inner inner in MoreInners)
            SelectAllInner(inner, list);
    }
}

public class Inner
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Inner> MoreInners { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to recurively loop through the object graph with Reflection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I am not sure his question is related to object graph. He is talking about nested classes and not about objects composition.