# C# recrusive limit all properties of type List with help of an attribute

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an instance of a very complex class, in which same properties of type `List` should be **limited** and the **last item** should be changed.

To implement this, I created an attribute, called `RangeLimitAttribute`, which contains the limit, the message and the property for the message.

But how do I get all instances of `List` **recursive** with this attribute from my object?

```
public class RangeLimitAttribute : Attribute
{
    public RangeLimitAttribute(int maxCount, string message, string messagePropertyname)
    {
        MaxCount = maxCount;
        this.Message = message;
        this.MessagePropertyname = messagePropertyname;
    }

    public string MessagePropertyname { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int MaxCount { get; set; }
}
```

Sample class:

```
public class Class
{
    [XmlAttribute("DisplayNameXYZ")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ErrorsXYZ")]
    [RangeLimit(100, "... more Errors", "Message")]
    public List<NestedClass> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class NestedClass
{
    [XmlAttribute("MessageXYZ")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FilesXYZ")]
    [RangeLimit(100, "... more Errors", "OtherProperty")]
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to reread the question and correct the language, i'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively Get Properties & Child Properties Of An Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220991/recursively-get-properties-child-properties-of-an-object) and a bit of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338018/how-to-get-a-property-value-using-reflection

Comment: Is this for validation of some sort ? Would the flow be something like Validator.Validate(object instance) ?