# Recursively find a property in an object

Tags: c#, recursion, reflection

I have a RootObject which can have multiple properties in it e.g A, B C below. RootObject is the result of an API call. It can have variable number of properties returned depending on the query used to call the API. In one call it may return A,B,C. For a different query it may return A,B,X,Y. When I get the RootObject I do not know what all properties it will have.

Now each property will have a screenshot object in it e.g. B->screenshot. Or it will have screenshot property burried under its sub property. eg. B->B1->Screenshot.

**Why I don't know properties upfront?** 
API call returns a JSON say fooJson. I deserialize that fooJson using a RootObject model.Sometimes after deserialization I get A,B,C. Another time I get A,B,X,Y.

**Question**

How can I get all the screenshot objects present in my RootObject? I want to get the following:

rootobject.a.s

rootobject.b.b1.s

```
public class RootObject
{
  A a;
  B b;
  C c;

}
public class A
{
  Screenshot S;
}
public class B
{
  B1 b1;

}
public class B1
{
  Screenshot S;
}
```

Comment: To better understand your question, why do you specifically mention recursion?

Comment: @Dan-Cook recursion is typically used for tree like data structures, in this case, the metadata tree of types and properties.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683581/c-sharp-reflection-with-recursion